# Using TLS in email sending

Tags: email, email-server, exim, tls

I've configured my server (Exim on Debian Linux) to send emails (with SMTP) **only** to email servers which accept TLS.

I did this so that nobody can steal a password reminder email.

Right decision? Do now (Apr 2016) almost all email server accept TLS in SMTP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do most SMTP servers support SSL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/605585/do-most-smtp-servers-support-ssl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question, based on [SSL Stats](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/email-port-statistics-1/) from Unlock The Inbox, it seems to suggest about 93 percent of all email servers that sent it incoming email support TLS on port 25.

Comment: This does not answer the question since the question is asking how many servers support receiving email over TLS and you answer how many servers support sending. Because the receiver need a certificate and the sender doesn't you can expect a smaller percentage to support receiving with TLS. There are mail software which in the default configuration can send over TLS but cannot receive.